# Vertical stacking of subfigures in standalone document class

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment, subfloats, standalone

I have a tikz drawing I want to export as a PDF. `\documentclass{standalone}` allows for the PDF to be cropped to the size of the drawing. However, the subfigures are then horizontally stacked. What can be done to vertically stack the subfigures with `\documentclass{standalone}`?

My MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows, shapes,shadows,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\tikzstyle{class} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=1cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered, draw=black, text = black]
\tikzstyle{process} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=1cm, minimum height=0.0cm,text centered, draw=white, text = black]
\tikzstyle{io} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered, draw=black, fill=white]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth, color=black]
\tikzstyle{container} = [draw, rectangle, dashed, rounded corners, minimum height = 1.6cm, minimum width=1.55cm]
\tikzstyle{note} = [rectangle, dashed, draw, fill=white, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=1.5cm, draw=black]
\usepackage{subfigure}
\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{(\Alph{subfigure})}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering

    \subfigure[Caption for sub figure A.]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 3.5cm]
    \node(MSa)[class]{MS};
    \node(trans)[process, right of = MSa]{$P^{\left(\text{\textit{trans}}\right)}$};
    \node(MSb)[class, right of = trans]{MS+1};
    \node(MSc)[class, below of = MSa, yshift = 1.8cm]{MS};
    
    \draw[arrow](MSa.east) -- node[above, scale = 0.8, align=left]{$U(T^{\uparrow}_{min},T^{\uparrow}_{max})$} (trans.west);
    \draw[arrow](trans.east) -- (MSb.west);
    \draw[arrow](trans.south) |- (MSc.east);
    \label{fig:MS dynamics prg}
    \end{tikzpicture}}
    
    \subfigure[Caption for sub figure B]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 3.5cm]
    \node(MSa)[class]{MS};
    \node(cure)[process, right of = MSa]{$P^{\left(\text{\textit{cure}}\right)}$};
    \node(MSb)[class, right of = cure]{MS-1};
    
    \draw[arrow]([yshift = 0.1cm]MSa.east) -- ([yshift = 0.1cm]cure.west);
    \draw[arrow](cure.east) -- node[above, scale = 0.8, align=left]{$U(T^{\downarrow}_{min},T^{\downarrow}_{max})$} (MSb.west);
    \draw[arrow]([yshift = -0.1cm]cure.west) -- ([yshift = -0.1cm]MSa.east);
    \label{fig:MS dynamics reg}
    \end{tikzpicture}}
 
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please taka look at [Should \tikzset or \tikzstyle be used to define TikZ styles?
](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52372/1952)

Comment: `subfigure` package is deprecated. It's better to use `subfig` or `subcaption`. See https://www.ctan.org/pkg/subfigure

Answer (score 2):

If you want and independent file, I don't understand the use of a `figure` environment with `subfigure` captions. In fact your code with `standalone` and `figure` doesn't compile.

In following solution, I've used a `tabular` to place both figures one above the other.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows, shapes,shadows,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\tikzstyle{class} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=1cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered, draw=black, text = black]
\tikzstyle{process} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=1cm, minimum height=0.0cm,text centered, draw=white, text = black]
\tikzstyle{io} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered, draw=black, fill=white]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth, color=black]
\tikzstyle{container} = [draw, rectangle, dashed, rounded corners, minimum height = 1.6cm, minimum width=1.55cm]
\tikzstyle{note} = [rectangle, dashed, draw, fill=white, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=1.5cm, draw=black]
\usepackage{subfigure}
\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{(\Alph{subfigure})}

\begin{document}
%\begin{figure}[h!]
%    \centering
\begin{tabular}{c}
%    \subfigure[Caption for sub figure A.]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 3.5cm]
    \node(MSa)[class]{MS};
    \node(trans)[process, right of = MSa]{$P^{\left(\text{\textit{trans}}\right)}$};
    \node(MSb)[class, right of = trans]{MS+1};
    \node(MSc)[class, below of = MSa, yshift = 1.8cm]{MS};
    
    \draw[arrow](MSa.east) -- node[above, scale = 0.8, align=left]{$U(T^{\uparrow}_{min},T^{\uparrow}_{max})$} (trans.west);
    \draw[arrow](trans.east) -- (MSb.west);
    \draw[arrow](trans.south) |- (MSc.east);
    \label{fig:MS dynamics prg}
    \end{tikzpicture}
%    }
    \\
%    \subfigure[Caption for sub figure B]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 3.5cm]
    \node(MSab)[class]{MS};
    \node(cure)[process, right of = MSab]{$P^{\left(\text{\textit{cure}}\right)}$};
    \node(MSbb)[class, right of = cure]{MS-1};
    
    \draw[arrow]([yshift = 0.1cm]MSab.east) -- ([yshift = 0.1cm]cure.west);
    \draw[arrow](cure.east) -- node[above, scale = 0.8, align=left]{$U(T^{\downarrow}_{min},T^{\downarrow}_{max})$} (MSbb.west);
    \draw[arrow]([yshift = -0.1cm]cure.west) -- ([yshift = -0.1cm]MSab.east);
    \label{fig:MS dynamics reg}
    \end{tikzpicture}
%    }
 \end{tabular}
%\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your problem can be solved by adding `varwidth` option to `standalone` document class:

```
\documentclass[%border=3mm, 
               varwidth]    % <---
               {standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, positioning, quotes}
\tikzset{
  arrow/.style = {thick,-stealth},
    lbl/.style = {font=\footnotesize, above},
  class/.style = {rectangle,  draw, rounded corners, minimum size=1cm, align=center},
process/.style = {class, draw=none, minimum size=1ex},
     io/.style = {class, minimum width=3cm, },
container/.style = {class, dashed, minimum sized=1.6cm},
   note/.style = {container},
every edge/.style = {draw, arrow},
every edge quotes/.style = {auto, font=\footnotesize}
            }
\usepackage{subfigure}
\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{(\Alph{subfigure})}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
\subfigure[Caption for sub figure A. \label{fig:MS dynamics prg}]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 22mm]
\node (MSa)  [class]{MS};
\node (trans)[process, right=of MSa] {$P^{\text{trans}}$};
\node (MSb)  [class, right=of trans] {MS+1};
\node (MSc)  [class, below=of MSa, yshift = 1.8cm]{MS};

\draw   (MSa)   edge ["${U(T^{\uparrow}_{\min},T^{\uparrow}_{\max})}$"] (trans) 
        (trans) edge (MSb);
\draw[arrow] (trans) |- (MSc);
    \end{tikzpicture}}

\bigskip
\subfigure[Caption for sub figure B \label{fig:MS dynamics reg}]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 22mm]
\node (MSab) [class]{MS};
\node (cure) [process, right=of MSab]{$P^{(\text{cure})}$};
\node (MSbb) [class, right=of cure]{MS-1};

\draw   ([yshift= 1mm] MSab.east) edge ([yshift = 0.1cm]cure.west)
        (cure) edge ["${U(T^{\uparrow}_{\min},T^{\uparrow}_{\max})}$"] (MSbb)
        ([yshift=-1mm] cure.west) edge ([yshift = -0.1cm]MSab.east);

    \label{fig:MS dynamics reg}
    \end{tikzpicture}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Interestingly, that in this case only deprecate package `subfigure` center sub caption horizontally. New packages `subfig` and `subcation` push caption to the left image border. For example:

```
\documentclass[%border=3mm, 
               varwidth     % <---
               ]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, positioning, quotes}
\tikzset{
  arrow/.style = {thick,-stealth},
    lbl/.style = {font=\footnotesize, above},
  class/.style = {rectangle,  draw, rounded corners, minimum size=1cm, align=center},
process/.style = {class, draw=none, minimum size=1ex},
     io/.style = {class, minimum width=3cm, },
container/.style = {class, dashed, minimum sized=1.6cm},
   note/.style = {container},
every edge/.style = {draw, arrow},
every edge quotes/.style = {auto, font=\footnotesize}
            }
\usepackage[skip=1ex, justification=centering]{subcaption}
\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{(\Alph{subfigure})}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
\subfloat[Caption for sub figure A  \label{fig:MS dynamics prg}]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 22mm]
\node (MSa)  [class]{MS};
\node (trans)[process, right=of MSa] {$P^{\text{trans}}$};
\node (MSb)  [class, right=of trans] {MS+1};
\node (MSc)  [class, below=of MSa, yshift = 1.8cm]{MS};

\draw   (MSa)   edge ["${U(T^{\uparrow}_{\min},T^{\uparrow}_{\max})}$"] (trans)
        (trans) edge (MSb);
\draw[arrow] (trans) |- (MSc);
    \end{tikzpicture}}

\bigskip
\subfloat[Caption for sub figure B \label{fig:MS dynamics reg}]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 22mm]
\node (MSab) [class]{MS};
\node (cure) [process, right=of MSab]{$P^{(\text{cure})}$};
\node (MSbb) [class, right=of cure]{MS-1};

\draw   ([yshift= 1mm] MSab.east) edge ([yshift = 0.1cm]cure.west)
        (cure) edge ["${U(T^{\uparrow}_{\min},T^{\uparrow}_{\max})}$"] (MSbb)
        ([yshift=-1mm] cure.west) edge ([yshift = -0.1cm]MSab.east);

    \label{fig:MS dynamics reg}
    \end{tikzpicture}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In both cases the code in your MWE is corrected writing of indices and by this shortened too.